# install iptables_nat module on centos 6.4

Tags: centos, iptables, nat

I am trying to add the following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

but what I am getting is:

```
FATAL: Module ip_tables not found.
iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Looking through the forums I came to the conclusion that the iptable_nat module is not installed/activated. By issuing

```
modprobe iptable_nat
```

I get

```
FATAL: Module iptable_nat not found.
```

Any ideas how to install/activate this.

Thanks, Adrian

Comment: And what is your kernel version?

Comment: Hi Michael. My kernel version is 2.6.18-028stab101.1

Comment: Contact your hosting provider. They must fix this issue for you.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the tip, I'll try to contact my hosting provider on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the output of below command and do you have enabled ip forwarding?

> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

should be 1.

> lsmod | grep iptable

Comment: Hi Bobbin, for the first command I get a 0. It is set to 0 in /etc/sysctl.conf. For the second I get nothing. Even when I run lsmod alone I get no modules...

Comment: You cannot or wont be able to load modules on a VPS, or if you have HW node then you have to rebuild kernal to enable iptable modules.

Comment: Bobbin, you are right they don't allow PREROUTING on VPS. Thanks.